# Textual progress in console?

Tags: dynamic, command-line, monitoring

Is there any way to get a textual progress bar (e.g. like the progressbar module in a python repl) when working in console mode?

Anything would be better than this:

[image]

Comment: `Monitor` doesn't seem to be supported either and `PrintTemporary` isn't exactly the answer. Just a comment.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this was discussed on a Wolfram livestream recently, so there might be some progress (sorry) on this functionality in upcoming versions.

Comment: Related answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/213537/how-to-create-a-progress-bar-using-wolframscript/213562#213562

Comment: Just use python, mma doesn’t support the command line in any modern way

Comment: how do you use python to run mma in the terminal?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a crude progress bar demo script that has been tested in a Gnome terminal under Linux and a Powershell command prompt under Windows 10.  Don't expect much because it's only a loop with a print statement:

```
progbar[width_, title_] := Function[{ndx},
    Print[ "  " <> title<>"\n  [" <>
            StringJoin@ConstantArray["*", ndx] <>
            StringJoin@ConstantArray[" ", width-ndx] <>
            "]" <> ToString[Round[100*ndx/width,1]] <>
            "%   \n\033[3A" ]
]

nsteps = 30;
pb = progbar[nsteps, "Crude Progress Bar"]

Table[ (*  put the function steps here *)
    Pause[1];

    (* follow the function steps with this one-line progress bar printer *)
    pb[ndx],
    {ndx, nsteps}
]

Print["\n\n"]
```

> Crude Progress Bar
>   [******************************]100%

So what's going on?  The `progbar[ ]` function returns a function that prints the progress bar.  It takes 2 arguments.  `width` is total number of steps, which should be an integer between, say, 10 and 100.  `title` is the message to printed above the progress bar.

The `pb = progbar[ ... ]` statement means `pb` will be called with the actual progress, probably a step number, between zero and `width`.  The variable name `width` makes sense in `progbar`, but the user might think of it as `nsteps`.

To monitor the training or testing of a machine learning algorithm, say, divide the training (or testing) task into chunks.  The number of chunks will be `width`, or `nsteps` in the above demo.  Perform the task in a loop and call `pb` with the loop index after each training with each chunk of data.  The above demo uses `Pause[1]` to represent the training (or testing) task.

What's the trick?  The only trick is to use an [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ANSI_escape_code&oldid=937809666) to `Print` on the same line every time.  The ANSI code "<kbd>ESC</kbd>[ 3 A"  moves the cursor up 3 lines.  There are many ANSI escape codes.  This one is an example of a [Terminal Output Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Terminal_output_sequences).

The `Print["\n\n"]` command is used to get the cursor back down below the progress bar after the task loop completes.

This has not been thoroughly tested, but one bug is known.  If we run the demo script like this `clear ; wolframscript -f progbardemo.wls`, it will be too close to the top edge of the terminal. So, `clear` the terminal and then enter the `wolframscript -f progbardemo.wls`.

**EDIT 1:**

The appearance of the progress bar could be improved if escape codes that turn the screen cursor on and off could be found.  The appearance could also be improved by judicious use of the well-known escape codes for color.

The progress bar does no error checking, so the user must ensure the argument of `pb` is an integer in the range of zero to `width`.  Here is an example of a random walk that uses the progress bar as an indicator widget.  Sometimes the walker wanders too far, and sometimes it comes back within range.  Error checking is done by "normalizing" the progress before.

```
nsteps = 50;
pb = progbar[nsteps, "Random Walker"]
progress = nsteps/2;
Do[
    progress += RandomChoice[{-1,1}/100];
    normal = Max[Min[Round[progress], nsteps], 0];
    pb[normal],

    {10000000}
]

Print["\n\n"]
```

**EDIT 2: Improving the Appearance**

The progress bar's appearance will be improved under some circumstances by hiding the screen cursor.  Use `Print["\033[?25l"]` before the loop to conceal the cursor and use `Print["\033[?25h"]` after the loop to reveal the cursor.  If the loop should fail for some reason, the code that reveals the cursor may not be evaluated.  If the WL script quits without revealing the cursor, the user will see the normal command line prompt, but without a cursor.  It may be possible to execute `python -c "print('\033[?25h')"` at the command prompt to reveal the cursor.  In Linux there is also a `tset` command that will reveal the screen cursor.