# How to create a progress bar using Wolframscript?

Tags: scripting, monitoring

I am using Wolfram script with a Mac OS. I have a long while loop dependent on the length of a list. i.e.:

```
myList = {}
While[ Length[myList] < 100, myList = AppendTo[myList, 0]]
```

How do I get a progress bar to appear in my terminal during this while loop?

Comment: That code does not make sense because `myList` is not defined, `While` does not have a test and a body separated by coma and if you put the coma that loop is infinite cause you are not increasing the length of `myList`.

Comment: It's an example, the point of the question is about the progress bar. "Corrected code":  
`myList = {};    While[ Length[myList] < 100, myList += {0,0}]`

Comment: Still an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is specific to Linux

```
k=1; 

While[ k<100, 

       k++; Pause@.1; 

      (* progress indicator *) 
       Run[ "echo -n '" <> 
            StringRepeat["|",k] <>  
            StringRepeat["-", 100-k] <> 
            "\r'"]
     ]
```

but you might find a command line that overwrites previous outputs like `echo -n  ' \r'` for other systems too.

Comment: hmm wolfram script doesn't seem to understand the return carriage. It prints on a new line every iteration. BTW I'm using a UNIX system so it should work

Comment: It is not wolfram that do not understand the return carriage, it is the shell of your operating system. As I wrote in the answer, you need to find command line that works for your OS.

Comment: Hmm using the above code and substituting the Run command for a WriteString command I get the expected output. This solution works for bash shells on Linux OS

Comment: @PHPHacky Great. I am on Debian 9 and only `Run` gives me the expected behaviour, not `WriteString`, What OS is yours?

Comment: macOS (which is Unix based) but I tested this on Linux as well. What shell are you using?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release